# WooCommerce database update ui

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

Summery(
Issue: Values in the database are updated but are not readable,
Goal: add variable products based on large JSON file
)

after adding products to the database directly, the products are unable to be read by the woocommerce UI.

The UI buttons are still able to change the data.

Even after the UI changes the value in the database, it is still unreadable in the database.

I suspect the issue is that there is another field I need to set for the ui to be able to grab the data.

Thank you for any help.

[ui before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLSIB.png) 
[database info before ui change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knl11.png)
[ui change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8r0s.png)
[database info after ui change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46X6N.png)

```
function wc_insert_term($ARGS){// needs name and slug
$table="wp_terms";
$data=array(
    //"term_id"=>"",// remove to add new
    "name"=>"test_val_0_name",
    "slug"=>"test_val_0_slug",
    "term_group"=>"0"
);
foreach($ARGS as $key => $value){
    $data[$key]=$value;
}

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->replace( $table, $data);
$id = $wpdb->insert_id;
return(array(
    "id"=>$id,
    "table"=>$table,
    "data"=>$data
));
```

}

```
function wc_insert_term_meta($ARGS){// needs term id and slug
$table="wp_termmeta";
$data=array(
    //"meta_id"=>"1",
    "term_id"=>"17",
    "meta_key"=>"order_pa_test_attr_slug",
    "meta_value"=>"0"
);
foreach($ARGS as $key => $value){
    $data[$key]=$value;
}
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->replace( $table, $data);
return(array(
    "id"=>$wpdb->insert_id,
    "table"=>$table,
    "data"=>$data
));
```

}

```
function wc_insert_term_relation($ARGS){// needs post_id and term id
$table="wp_term_relationships";
$data=array(
    //"meta_id"=>"1",
    "object_id"=>"7",// post parent id or self post id
    "term_taxonomy_id"=>"18",// term_tax id
    "term_order"=>"0"
);
foreach($ARGS as $key => $value){
    $data[$key]=$value;
}
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->replace( $table, $data);
return(array(
    "id"=>$wpdb->insert_id,
    "table"=>$table,
    "data"=>$data
));
```

}

```
function wc_insert_term_tax($ARGS){// needs term_id , slug , description
$table="wp_term_taxonomy";
$data=array(
    //"term_taxonomy_id"=>"17",
    "term_id"=>"17",
    "taxonomy"=>"pa_test_attr_slug",
    "description"=>"test_val_0_descript",
    "parent"=>"0",
    "count"=>"0"
);
foreach($ARGS as $key => $value){
    $data[$key]=$value;
}

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->replace( $table, $data);
return(array(
    "id"=>$wpdb->insert_id,
    "table"=>$table,
    "data"=>$data
));
```

}

```
function wc_assign_product_attr($ARGS){// this function assignes a term to a post
$data=array(
    "post_id"=>"0",
    "tax_id"=>"0"
);

foreach($ARGS as $key => $value){
    $data[$key]=$value;
}

$post_id=$data["post_id"];
$tax_id=$data["tax_id"];

wc_insert_term_relation(array(
    "object_id"=>"$post_id",
    "term_taxonomy_id"=>"$tax_id"
));
```

}